# R Code works fine in RStudio but not in terminal - ODBC SQL - Failed to load the security library: (libgssapi_krb5.dylib)

Tags: r, sql-server, terminal, odbc, rstudio

I have some R code made in RStudio. It connects to SQL-Server, runs a query and saves out a csv.

It runs fine in RStudio but i want it to run in terminal so I can schedule it daily.

I have tried googling the error message for I can't seem to find what im looking for.

The SQL server authenticates with Windows Auth. Therefor im not suppling a username and password.

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),.connection_string = "Driver={Simba SQL Server ODBC Driver}; 
Server=MYSERVER;
Database=TEST;
trusted_connection=true")
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: HY000: [Simba][Support] (50366) Failed to load the security library: (libgssapi_krb5.dylib) 
Execution halted

I'm really new to R so I'm not too sure whats happening, any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!